# why file_put_contents show dialog save file?

Tags: php

Using the following code I'm saving a `.csv` file on the server

```
foreach($list as $item)
{ 
    $csv .= join("\t", $item) . "\r\n"; 
}  

$csv = chr(255).chr(254).mb_convert_encoding($csv,"UTF-16LE","UTF-8");
header("Content-type: application/x-msdownload");
header("Content-disposition: csv; filename=CSV_".date("YmdHis").".csv; size=".strlen($csv));
$filename='CSV_'.$dateTimeNow.".csv";
file_put_contents($filename, $csv); // Create temp file
```

The `.csv` is successfully saved but the client is still receiving a download dialogue. How can I stop the download dialogue from showing?

Comment: What are you setting those headers for if you do not want the client to download something?!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the CSV file is not intended to be sent to the client system, then you should not be setting headers that imply that you're sending a .csv file to the client i.e. remove the `header` lines that causes this response to the client.

Comment: Or just remove the headers altogether since he doesn't want the client to download the file.

Comment: ah, I read this question as 'for a download'. Cripes, why is he setting headers for something that is not being sent to the client?

Answer (score 0):

```
  // header("Content-type: application/x-msdownload");
  // header("Content-disposition: csv; filename=CSV_".date("YmdHis").".csv; size=".strlen($csv));
```